# Keeping custom module synced in OpenERP7

Tags: python, odoo, pycharm, openerp-7

SO i'm using Open ERP 7 and wanted to make a custom module. I've put everything into PyCharm to edit parts there, but sometimes I edit some forms or add some fields with in OpenERP itself under the Database structure.

Any changes I make under the Database Structure (e.g adding a field) won't show up in my PyCharm. Is there a way to keep them both in sync?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to tell that you are adding any field or any view from openerp view side under settings tab.?

Answer (score 0):

Any change made directly in the OpenERP/Odoo GUI is not written back to the module and will overwritten in the next module upgrade.

Use those direct changes only for experimenting or fast prototyping.
Changes you mean to be final should always be made in your module files.